# get embedded resourses in doc files using apache tika

Tags: java, apache-tika

I have ms word documents containing text and images. I want to parse them to have xml structure for them. After researching I end up using apache tika for converting my documents. I can parse my doc to xml. here is my code:

```
AutoDetectParser parser=new AutoDetectParser();
InputStream input=new FileInputStream(new File("1.docx"));
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
SAXTransformerFactory factory = (SAXTransformerFactory)SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
TransformerHandler handler = factory.newTransformerHandler();
handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
handler.setResult(new StreamResult(sw));

parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, new ParseContext());
String xhtml = sw.toString();
```

I want to extract images from document and convert them to binary format. I don't know how to extract embedded resources from document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define your own class which implements `Parser` and attach that to the `ParseContext` you supply when parsing the outer document. Your Parser will then be called for all embedded resources, allowing you to save them out if you want to

The best example I can think of for this is in the Tika CLI, as used by the `-z` (extract) flag. If you look in the [source code for TikaCLI](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-app/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/cli/TikaCLI.java), you're looking for the `FileEmbeddedDocumentExtractor` as your example.

The simplest code would be something like:

```
final AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();

public class ExtractParser extends AbstractParser {
   private int att = 0;
   public Set<MediaType> getSupportedTypes(ParseContext context) {
     // Everything AutoDetect parser does
     return parser.getSupportedTypes(context);
   }
   public void parse(
        InputStream stream, ContentHandler handler,
        Metadata metadata, ParseContext context)
        throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {
      // Stream to a new file
      File f = new File("out-" + (++att) + ".bin");
      FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
      IOUtils.copy(strea, fout);
      fout.closee();
   }
}

InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("1.docx"));
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
context.set(Parser.class, extractParser);
parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, context);
```

You can also use the `EmbeddedDocumentExtractor` interface if you'd rather, depends on what you want to do if it's better to use Parser directly

Comment: and another question. in parse method is it possible to find out the format of output embedded file declared in supported type and put correct type instead of .bin?

Comment: You can look up the suggested extension from the MimeTypesRegistry

Comment: i wonder why Tika does not support this functionality in a Parser, only in the CLI

Comment: @OhadR Tika does support it from the CLI! Just use code similar to the above, customised for your  own requirements!

Comment: i meant that if i use tika as a dependencyin my code - not from the CLI - i do not have access to the "FileEmbeddedDocumentExtractor"

Comment: @OhadR You don't need it! Just use the code from my answer and you're set

Comment: but I do want the functionality of FileEmbeddedDocumentExtractor, that puts all extracted items into a different directory... this is why i suggest it should be extracted from CLI to tika-core...