# Apache-Tika & Java: parsing documents (.docx, .pdf) INCLUDING images, and use images in generated .xhtml file

Tags: java, pdf, xhtml, docx, apache-tika

I need to parse various document formats (eg: *.docx*, *.pdf*) and convert their content (**including**) to an *.xhtml* file. I'm using Apache Tika 1.17 (as maven dependency) in a Java project

I've analyzed several already existing questions about this ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172465/get-embedded-resourses-in-doc-files-using-apache-tika), [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783212/extract-images-from-pdf-with-apache-tika)), and using a custom `EmbeddedDocumentExtractor`, I was able to extract the included *.png* images alongside the generated *.xhtml* file.

***The problem*** is that in both cases (*.docx* and *.pdf* input files), inside the generated *.xhtml* file, the images are referred to not simply by their name, instead using this kind of syntax:

> `<img src="embedded:image5.png" alt="image0.png" />`.

So only the content of the *alt* element is displayed, not the image itself.

Could I somehow change / configure this ?

Would it be possible to somehow **include** the images inside the *.xhtml* file, as binary data ?

Or what other options would I have around this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: Write your own custom Content Handler that re-writes the src to refer to wherever you've chosen to save the embedded images to?

Comment: Thanks, that's the approach that I chose in the end...
Would you know how such custom ContentHandler would have to be coded, to somehow "intercept" exactly the _<img..._ elements, so that I don't have to manually parse the resulted String after that ? I can't seem to find an example for this situation...

Comment: Take a look at `TikaImageRewritingContentHandler` from Alfresco for one example - that re-writes the embedded image links to be absolute for images stored in a certain path, I think that's basically what you need: https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition-old/blob/master/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/rendition/executer/HTMLRenderingEngine.java